# Can we somehow create Server Side Filters using Python?

Tags: python, imap

I get around 100k mails everyday and client side filters are not working due to crash of Outlook and Thunderbird. I wrote following code in Python to delete all messages:

```
import imaplib
box = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.microsoftonline.com', 993)
box.login("userid@nextag.microsoftonline.com","password")
box.select('Inbox')
typ, data = box.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
 box.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
box.expunge()
box.close()
box.logout()
```

But then I am getting socket error. If somehow I can create filters on Server Side using python, then it would be really easy for me to handle these emails.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with you closing the connection before logging out.

Comment: Actually, its happening because of too much load .. . Anyways, the main mission is not deleting all messages I have but rather manage them somehow.. . So anyidea how I can create server side filters?